# How to convert a Uri to a FilePath in a VS Code Language Server?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a VS Code extension you can convert a uri to a filePath like this:

```
import {Uri} from 'vscode';
let uri = 'file:///c%3A/WINDOWS/file.txt';  
let path:string = Uri.parse(uri).fsPath;
```

However, in a language server this does not work, beacuse importing vscode fails.
The reason for this is the fact that vscode is "not a real node_module"
[vscode issue #6586](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6586)
after successfully running,

```
node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install
```

when the language server is started it still does not find the module:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
```

What is the best way to transform a Uri to a filePath in a platform independent way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft has moved this [package](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-uri), so you need to do this:

First add as a dependency:

```
npm install --save vscode-uri
```

And then in your program:

```
import Uri from 'vscode-uri'
```