# Manipulate Observable response

Tags: angular, observable

I have a list of resources retrieved from a rest api call to Observable object.
These resources can have such values:

> {Name: 'French', Uri: 'file:///C:.../french.csv'},
>   {Name: "DB2", Dbms: "DB2", Host: "...", Port: 50000, DbName: "..."}

I need to determine based on the Dbms value if the resource is a DB resource or a File Resource in order to be displayed on the Type column in my table later and be able to filter by it...

I think the map is the best place to do it, but still can't figure out how exactly:

```
 getResources(user): Observable<Array<any>> {
    const url = this.url + this.apiAllowedPath + user + '/resources';
    return this.http.get(url)
        .flatMap((response) => response.json())
        .map( (response) => response.Dbms ? "DB : File/Folder"; )
        .catch((response: Response) => this.errorHandler(response) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create an array where each object has `type` property showing its source type.

```
getResources(user): Observable<Array<any>> {
    const url = this.url + this.apiAllowedPath + user + '/resources';
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .map(data => data.map(o => ({
          ...o, 
          type: o.Dbms ? 'DB' : 'FILE',
          path: Uri.parse(o.Uri).fsPath
         })))
        .catch((response: Response) => this.errorHandler(response) );
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. what is the "..." cause if I add that line with: o => {...o, Type: o.Dbms ? 'DB' : 'File/Folder'})         I get error in other location in my source code  (338,49): Cannot find name 'editMode'.

Comment: I did this instead: .map(data => data.map( item => item.Type = item.Dbms ? 'DB' : 'File/Folder' ) )   and I got in my result only the Types (without other fields)

Comment: edited it, try again now. "..." is a spread operator introduced in es6.

Comment: working like a charm, thank you very much... saved me a lot of time.

Comment: What if I want to change existing value? The Path currently is retrieved as URI: file:///C:/TDF/TDFApplicationData/files/KnowledgeBase/french.csv  and I want to display it as path using vscode-uri (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658425/how-to-convert-a-uri-to-a-filepath-in-a-vs-code-language-server)

Comment: I mean something like this: 

.map(response => response.json())
            .map({Uri} => Uri.parse(uri).fsPath )
            .map(data => data.map(o => ({...o, Type: o.Dbms ? 'DB' : 'File/Folder'})))

Comment: actually I can use the same trick and add a new value called Path instead of Uri then use it in my table - please ignore   
.map(data => data.map(o => ({...o, Path: Uri.parse(data.Uri).fsPath})) )

Answer (score 0):

After you have use the map operator the result is string value either `DB` or `File/Folder`
so you don't the actual server respond;

you can do something like this

```
interface DataResponse{
  db:any[];
  file:any[];
}

getResources(user): Observable<DataResponse> {
   const url = this.url + this.apiAllowedPath + user + '/resources';
   return this.http.get(url)
            .flatMap((response) => response.json())
            .map( (response) =>{ 
                 let db = response.filter(i => response.hasOwnProperty('Dbms') );
                 let file = response.filter(i =>!response.hasOwnProperty('Dbms'));
                return {db,file}
                })
            .catch((response: Response) => this.errorHandler(response) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need it in same object. Tried this as well but still no luck: return this.http.get(url)
            .map( (response) => response.json() )
            .map(({Name, Dbms, Host, Port, DbName, Uri}) => 
                new GlobalResource(Dbms ? "DB" : "File/Folder"
                    , Name
                    , Dbms
                    , Host
                    , Port
                    , DbName
                    , Uri)
            )

Comment: getting: Type 'Observable<{} | GlobalResource>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.

Comment: I will update my answer arrow function () => this will faild

Comment: the old object will be data property

Comment: do you mean a response continue a list of db and file , what about get a list of file and db in this case you have an object contains both but separate

Comment: Yes, the response will contain both DB & File resources.. I can't seperate it at this point.

Comment: @zbeedatm I have update my answer in this way you will got an object contine db and file data seprate

Comment: Thanks for your support Muhammad. it worked for me with the other solution